# Elasticsearch Histogram on the doc_count Field of an Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, join, inner-join

I'm trying to determine how many events occurred twice given two specified time periods. Ideally I would have the following queries: 
1) Filter on the year 2016
2) Filter on the year 2017
3) Do an inner join of the output of these two filters on the "Key" field to find the values that exist in both queries.

Alternatively, I would like to be able to do an aggregation and create a histogram on the "doc_count" field that is output by this aggregation.

Are either of these possible within elasticsearch?